# Python 3 : How to print output to both Console and File

Tags: python, windows, file, python-3.x, terminal

So basically I'm still learning Python programming and currently playing around with some code I found on github.

Basically, the code works fine when execute, it print the output to terminal/console. However I would like to save the output to file and therefore followed few tutorials and successfully saved the output to file but the output didn't display in the terminal.

My question is, how to execute this python script to display the output on the terminal and at the same time write the output to .txt file?

Below are the python code I'm working on:

```
import os
import warnings
import argparse
import sys
import unicodedata

from PIL import Image


COLORS = [

    [0,     (255,255,255),  '97',   'white'],
    [1,     (0,0,0),        '30',   'black'],
    [2,     (0,0,127),      '34',   'blue'],
    [3,     (0,147,0),      '32',   'green'],
    [4,     (255,0,0),      '91',   'light red'],
    [5,     (127,0,0),      '31',   'brown'],
    [6,     (156,0,156),    '35',   'purple'],
    [7,     (252,127,0),    '33',   'orange'],
    [8,     (255,255,0),    '93',   'yellow'],
    [9,     (0,252,0),      '92',   'light green'],
    [10,    (0,147,147),    '36',   'cyan'],
    [11,    (0,255,255),    '96',   'light cyan'],
    [12,    (0,0,252),      '94',   'light blue'],
    [13,    (255,0,255),    '95',   'pink'],
    [14,    (127,127,127),  '90',   'grey'],
    [15,    (210,210,210),  '37',   'light grey']
]

def convert(img, doColor=True, renderIRC=True, cutoff=50, size=1.0, invert=False, alphaColor=(0,0,0)):
    i = Image.open(img)

    WIDTH = int(90*size)
    HIGHT = int(40*size)

    # Resize the image to fix bounds
    s = i.size
    if s[0]==0 or s[1]==0 or (float(s[0])/float(WIDTH))==0 or (float(s[1])/float(HIGHT))==0:
        return []
    ns = (WIDTH,int(s[1]/(float(s[0])/float(WIDTH))))
    if ns[1]>HIGHT:
        ns = (int(s[0]/(float(s[1])/float(HIGHT))),HIGHT)

    i2 = i.resize(ns)

    bimg = []

    for r in range(0,i2.size[1],4):
        line = u''
        lastCol = -1
        for c in range(0,i2.size[0],2):
            val = 0
            i = 0
            cavg = [0,0,0]
            pc = 0

            for ci in range(0,4):
                for ri in range(0,3 if ci<2 else 1):
                    # Convert back for the last two pixels
                    if ci>=2:
                        ci-=2
                        ri=3

                    # Retrieve the pixel data
                    if c+ci<i2.size[0] and r+ri<i2.size[1]:
                        p = i2.getpixel((c+ci,r+ri))
                        alpha = p[3] if len(p)>3 else 1
                        if invert and alpha>0:
                            p = map(lambda x: 255-x, p)
                        elif alpha==0:
                            p = alphaColor
                    else:
                        p = (0,0,0)

                    # Check the cutoff value and add to unicode value if it passes
                    luma = (0.2126*float(p[0]) + 0.7152*float(p[1]) + 0.0722*float(p[2]))
                    pv = sum(p[:3])
                    if luma > cutoff:
                        val+=1<<i
                        cavg = map(sum,zip(cavg,p))
                        pc+=1
                    i += 1

            if doColor and pc>0:
                # Get the average of the 8 pixels
                cavg = map(lambda x:x/pc,cavg)

                # Find the closest color with geometric distances
                colorDist = lambda c:sum(map(lambda x:(x[0]-x[1])**2,zip(cavg,c[1])))
                closest = min(COLORS, key=colorDist)

                if closest[0]==1 or lastCol==closest[0]:
                    # Check if we need to reset the color code
                    if lastCol!=closest[0] and lastCol!=-1:
                        line+='\x03' if renderIRC else '\033[0m'
                    line += unichr(0x2800+val)
                else:
                    # Add the color escape to the first character in a set of colors
                    if renderIRC:
                        line += ('\x03%u'%closest[0])+unichr(0x2800+val)
                    else:
                        line += ('\033[%sm'%closest[2])+unichr(0x2800+val)
                lastCol = closest[0]
            else:
                # Add the offset from the base braille character
                line += unichr(0x2800+val)
        bimg.append(line)
    return bimg


if __name__=='__main__':
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument('file', help='The image file to render')
    ap.add_argument('-c',type=int,default=100, help='The luma cutoff amount, from 0 to 255. Default 50')
    ap.add_argument('-s', type=float, default=1.0, help='Size modifier. Default 1.0x')
    ap.add_argument('--nocolor', action="store_true", default=False, help='Don\'t use color')
    ap.add_argument('--irc', action="store_true", default=False, help='Use IRC color escapes')
    ap.add_argument('--invert', action="store_true", default=False, help='Invert the image colors')
    ap.add_argument('--background', default='black', help='The color to display for full alpha transparency')
    ap.add_argument('-f', help="Write to text file")
    args = ap.parse_args()

    alphaColor = (0,0,0)
    for c in COLORS:
        if c[3].lower() == args.background:
            alphaColor = c[1]
            break

    for u in convert(args.file,doColor=not args.nocolor, renderIRC=args.irc, cutoff=args.c, size=args.s, invert=args.invert, alphaColor=alphaColor): 
        #sys.stdout = open('I put my path here to .txt file','a')
        print u.encode('utf-8')
    #sys.stdout.close()
```

Look at the very few last line statement to print the output.

PS: This is not my code, I'm just trying learn some ASCII art through python.
PSS: I'm using Windows with Cygwin64 Terminal to execute the code.

With Regards.

Comment: Hmm, not really a great question for S.O.... it is simple: just use two commands - one for console and one for the file!

Comment: FYI, the Windows 10 console [supports VT100 terminal control sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt638032).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting `stdout` to be your file, keep it to be the default and use file I/O operations to write to the file while printing.

```
# open the file
f = open('I put my path here to .txt file','a')
for u in convert(args.file,doColor=not args.nocolor, renderIRC=args.irc, cutoff=args.c, size=args.s, invert=args.invert, alphaColor=alphaColor):
    toWrite = u.encode('utf-8')
    # write to the file
    f.write(toWrite)
    print toWrite
# close the file
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally can print to both terminal and text file! Love u so much :*